# Limit input file upload depend on category and style

Tags: html, jquery

my current code allow to add more input field to upload.

Is there any way to limit it depend on selected category and style?

```
    <div class="form-group form-inline mb-2">
        <label class="categories">Category</label>
            <select name="category" id="cat" class="form-control mx-sm-2 ">
                <option value="1">Category 1</option>
                <option value="2">Category 2</option>

            </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-inline mb-2">
        <label class="styles">Style</label>
            <select name="style" id="style" class="form-control mx-sm-2">
                <option value="1">Style 1</option>
                <option value="2">Style 2</option>
                <option value="3">Style 3</option>
                <option value="4">Style 4</option>
                <option value="5">Style 5</option>
            </select>
    </div>

                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="entry input-group upload-input-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="image[]" type="file">
                                        <button class="btn btn-upload btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
```

my current ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
        var cat = $("#cat").val();
            var stl = $("#style").val();
        var max_fields = 5;
        var x = 1;
        if(cat==2){
            if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                        var controlForm = $('.controls:first'),
                        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

                        newEntry.find('input').val('');
                        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                        .html('<span class="fa fa-trash"></span>');
            }
            else{
            alert('Maximum '+max_fields+' IMAGEs are allowed.');
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Maximum 1 IMAGE are allowed.');
        }
            });
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function (e) {
                $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });

});
</script>
```

i want if i select category 1 it will show message allow maximum is 1 input field if select category 2 it will allow maximum 5 input field.

i dont know why it still allow to add unlimit.

Thank you!

Comment: It is simple jQuery and html. Where is php and ajax?

Comment: You just need to get `$('#cat').val` and `$('#style').val` and check them and according to it do your append operations

Comment: what if user select category 2 and style 1  then what should happen ?

Comment: @Swati the user can not add more input field

Comment: simply use `if ($(".entry").length < $("#style").val()) { //your add code here }`

Comment: @Swati updated my jquery. Can you see what wrong? it still allow unlimit fields

Comment: Hi, its because you are using `var x = 1;` inside click handler so everytime button is click the value of `x` is initialize to `1` . So , to solve this simply put that `var x = 1;` outside event handler.